# Como pego o que está escrito num campo de texto no HTML e transfiro para uma variável PHP?

Tags: php, html

O que eu preciso fazer é o seguinte, eu tenho um sistema de upload de arquivos com edição e exclusão após ser feito o upload, ao clicar para alterar aquele arquivo você pode alterar a descrição e o arquivo em si.

Por exemplo:

Descrição: Teste 1
Arquivo: Apostila1.pdf

O que eu quero é que quando eu clicar para alterar o arquivo, a descrição, que nesse caso é "Teste 1", já apareça no campo de texto, ao invés dele aparecer vazio.
Como faço isso?
No java era só pegar o que está no textfield e colocar numa variável e escrever no textfield, mas em PHP eu não sei como vou fazer isso.

Comment: Seria legal você posta um pedaço do seu código aqui. Tentar explicar melhor o que quer fazer. Creio que é fácil mas precisamos nos certificar que entendemos sua pergunta.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

No seu campo de texto colocar um nome dele usando o parâmetro Exemplo name=variavel...

No seu form que irá ter o campo de texto, especifique a action (action="arquivo.php") e o method que você irá usar para enviar a informação (method='GET')... Trabalhe primeiro com GET para você ir vendo como o processo ocorre dentro do navegador pela URL... No seu arquivo PHP que será o especificado na action você irá pegar o dado do seu campo desta forma.

Código Exemplo
DENTRO DO ARQUIVO HTML (INDEX.HTML)

```
<form action='arquivo.php' method='GET'>
<input name='variavel' type="text"/>
</form>
```

DENTRO DO ARQUIVO PHP(arquivo.php)

```
<?php
$textoDoCampo = $_GET['variavel']; << Sim esse variavel dentro do GET é o name do seu campo de texto feito no html.
?>
```

Ai por diante você pode utilizar ele ($textoDoCampo) como preferir.

Comment: Muito obrigado ^^